# Function inside Function; variable changing unwantedly, why? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

So I just started writing few lines of code a few days ago, and I wanted to make a calculator with the knowledge I gained so far but for a reason I don’t know, after calling `CalculationFN()` inside `ReCalFN()` I see that the variables of `num2` and `act` change. Why is that and how can I fix it?
//why does the variable of `num2` change to undefined after going inside `ReCalFN()`
I know there are better ways to make a calculator but this is i guess my edition.
if you suggest any thing please say, I do Appreciate. (and sorry for my english). Thank you for reading.

```js
//Input start
var num1 = prompt("Num1");
if ( ( num1 <= 0 ) || ( num1 > 0 ) ) {

  var act = prompt("Action");
  if ( (act == "+") || (act == "-") || (act == "*") || (act == "/") ||
  (act == "%") ) {

    var num2 = prompt("Num2");
    if ( ( num2 <= 0 ) || ( num2 > 0 ) ) {
//Input end

//Calculator start

function CalculationFN () {

alert(num1); alert(act); alert(num2);

  switch ( act ) {

        case "+":
           num1 = +num1 + +num2;
            ReCalFN ();
            break;

        case "-":
           num1 = +num1 - +num2;
            ReCalFN ();
            break;

        case "*":
           num1 = +num1 * +num2;
            ReCalFN ();
            break;

        case "/":
           if ( ( act == "/" ) && ( num2 == 0) )
           { alert("Error: Undifiend"); } else {
            num1 = +num1 / +num2; }
             ReCalFN ();
            break;

        case "%":
           num1 = +num1 * +num2 /100;
            ReCalFN ();
            break;

          }

       }

//.............................

       function ReCalFN () {

         var act = prompt(" " + num1 + "\n New Action");
         if ( (act == "+") || (act == "-") || (act == "*") || (act == "/") ||
         (act == "%") ) {
           
//"num2 = undifined" why?...................
alert(num1); alert(act); alert(num2);

           var num2 = prompt("AnyNum");
           if ( ( num2 <= 0 ) || ( num2 > 0 ) ) {

alert(num1); alert(act); alert(num2);

     CalculationFN ();

           } else { alert("Error: no valid action"); }

         } else { alert("Error: no valid value"); }
       }

CalculationFN ();

//Calculator end

//Error start
    } else { alert("Error: no valid value"); }
  } else { alert("Error: no valid action"); }
} else { alert("Error: no valid value"); }
//Error end
```

Comment: Because you've declared a local variable (`var num2 …`) that is `undefined` at the time you alert it. It's a different variable (though with the same name, in a different scope) than the global `num2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring `num2` inside of `ReCalFN`, so `num2` refers to that new local variable instead of the global one. All variable declarations are moved to the top of the function due to JavaScript [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).

So, your `ReCalFN` function is equivalent to this:

```
function ReCalFN () {
     // hoisted variables
     var act;
     var num2;  // declared but not assigned, is not the global variable
     act = prompt(" " + num1 + "\n New Action");
     if ( (act == "+") || (act == "-") || (act == "*") || (act == "/") ||
     (act == "%") ) {

       // num2 is undefined
       alert(num1); alert(act); alert(num2);

       num2 = prompt("AnyNum");  // num2 has a value from now on
       if ( ( num2 <= 0 ) || ( num2 > 0 ) ) {
         // num2 is not undefined
         alert(num1); alert(act); alert(num2);

         CalculationFN ();

       } else { alert("Error: no valid action"); }

     } else { alert("Error: no valid value"); }
   }
```

Consider avoiding global variables and side effects. Pass the variables you need as arguments.

Comment: So I Just have to remove the var in ReCalFN so it would update num2 and act not creat them as local variables. Thank you